# matplotlib gridspec multiple plots and different types of graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

[How does it look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa4bJ.png)

At first I developed this code to work only with pie charts. WORKING CODE BELOW.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
#coding=utf8
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
#mpl.use('Agg')
#import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np



fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
graph_grid=GridSpec(1,3)


datas=[[(u'hangup', 480L), (u'invalid', 46L), (u'one', 1235L), (u'repeat', 153L), (u'three', 987L), (u'two', 2379L), (u'wait', 810L)],
[(u'hangBut', 2L), (u'gotoButik', 113L), (u'goBackfrom', 29L), (u'fromIM2Hot', 398L), (u'choice3_to', 1L), (u'choice2_to', 1L)],
[(0L, 5L), (1L, 6L), (2L, 9L), (9L, 419L), (10L, 609L), (11L, 685L), (12L, 694L), (13L, 639L), (14L, 611L), (15L, 566L), (16L, 523L), (17L, 484L), (18L, 327L), (19L, 253L), (20L, 155L), (21L, 61L), (22L, 33L), (23L, 11L)]]

counter=0
for ds in datas:

    labels=[ k[0] for k in ds]
    vals=[ k[1] for k  in ds]
    ziplists=zip(vals,labels)
    ziplists=sorted(ziplists,reverse=True)
    vals, labels = zip(*ziplists)
    total=sum(vals)
    plt.subplot(graph_grid[0,counter], aspect=1)
    #print len(labels)
    #print len(vals)
    print()
    plt.title("title")
    if counter <= 1:
       piechart=plt.pie(vals, autopct=lambda(p): '{:.0f}'.format(p * total / 100), shadow=True,pctdistance=1.2)
       plt.legend(piechart[0], labels, loc="lower right",  prop={'size': 6}, bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 0.04),)
    elif counter == 2:
        ypos=np.arange(len(labels))
        print ypos
        print len(vals)
        plt.bar(ypos,vals,color='red', width=0.3 )

        plt.xticks(ypos,vals)
        plt.xlabel(u'hours')
        plt.ylabel(u'count')
    counter+=1

fig.tight_layout()
fig.set_size_inches(w=11, h=7)

plt.show()
```

It looked good. Mostly. But some data could look better in barchart. Said - done.
Sadly, barchart is drawn too narrow and I am almost unable to change it's size.
Some crazy values of width, like witdth=1000 do some work, but still graph looks crappy. Where is the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: Why minus? Please tell me!

Comment: Can the down voters explain why they are down voting? Just hitting down vote without giving a reason is a really bad practice. This isn't some unattempted question without any effort from the OP.  @everstarter: It would be helpful if you can provide a working code with data so that people can reproduce your figure.

Comment: Yes. It can take a bit of time because data is generated. I will create static data set.

Comment: Working code is attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the aspect ratio of the bar chart to 1, the same as the pie charts. If you remove this the bar chart becomes readable.

I would perhaps put the `plt.subplot(...)` in the `if` statements so you can control when you set the aspect ratio:

```
if counter <= 1:
    plt.subplot(graph_grid[0,counter], aspect=1)
    # pie charts here

elif counter == 2:
    plt.subplot(graph_grid[0,counter])
    # bar chart here
```

which gives the following image (you may have to rotate the x axis ticks on the bar chart to make it look nice):

[image]